# PHPExcel Piechart labels and legends

Tags: charts, phpexcel, pie-chart

I have a problem with the library PHPExcel (1.7.7): When I want to create a piechart, labels and legends are not displayed. However, with other graphics, I do not have that problem. Do you have any a solution?

Thanks.

Here is the code used:

```
$categories = array(
new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'RECAPITULATIF!$B$6:$B$8', null, 3),
    );

$values = array(
new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number',  'RECAPITULATIF!$F$6:$F$8', null, 3),
);

$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_PIECHART,       // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED,  // plotGrouping
    array(0),                                       // plotOrder
    null,                                           // plotLabel
    $categories,                                    // plotCategory
    $values                                         // plotValues
    );

$plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(null, array($series));
$title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Pie chart');
$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, null, false);

$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart2',                                       // name
    $title,                                         // title
    $legend,                                        // legend
    $plotarea,                                      // plotArea
    true,                                           // plotVisibleOnly
    0,                                              // displayBlanksAs
    null,                                           // xAxisLabel
    null                                            // yAxisLabel
    );
```

Comment: isn't it because ur setting null for xAxisLabel and yAxisLabel ?

Answer (score 7):

We have to enable data labels by declaring the setShowVal(TRUE).

Find the following code I applied

```
$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,       // plotType
PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED,  // plotGrouping
array(0, 1),                                    // plotOrder
$labels,                                        // plotLabel
$categories,                                    // plotCategory
$values                                         // plotValues
);

$layout1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_Layout();
$layout1->setShowVal(TRUE);      // Initializing the data labels with Values
$layout1->setShowPercent(TRUE);  // Initializing the data labels with Percentages
```

The applied plot area needs to be declared

```
$series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);
$plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea($layout1, array($series));
$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, null, false);
$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
        'chart1',                                       // name
        null,                                           // title
        $legend,                                        // legend
        $plotarea,                                      // plotArea
        true,                                           // plotVisibleOnly
        0,                                              // displayBlanksAs
        null,                                           // xAxisLabel
        null                                            // yAxisLabel
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Aren't u getting this problem because ur forgetting to set a xAxisLabel and yAxisLabel?

Try creating an array getting the labels u want to set and then load it in this array like u were doing, but setting the plotLabel.
for example: for the labels:

```
$labels = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$B$1', null, 1),
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$C$1', null, 1),
);

$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_PIECHART,       // plotType
PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED,  // plotGrouping
array(0),                                       // plotOrder
$labels,                                           // plotLabel <----- u were setting null
$categories,                                    // plotCategory
$values                                         // plotValues
);
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
$xAxisLabel = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('xAxisLabel');
$yAxisLabel = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('yAxisLabel');
```

and then:

```
$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
'chart2',                                       // name
$title,                                         // title
$legend,                                        // legend
$plotarea,                                      // plotArea
true,                                           // plotVisibleOnly
0,                                              // displayBlanksAs
xAxisLabel,                                     // xAxisLabel
yAxisLabel                                      // yAxisLabel
);
```

Comment: Stille doesn't work! And I can not find documentation or examples of PHPExcel.

Comment: did u download it from github? the documentation is right here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/develop/Documentation

Comment: maybe this discussion here can help you: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/359273

Comment: I just saw u set null for plot label too.. I'll edit my answer

Comment: but are you setting the xaxislabel and yaxislabel?

Comment: yes and also without xaxislabel and yaxislabel. I tried to set plotLabel (array) without effect...

Answer (score 3):

I know it's really late, But i think answer should be given here.
I am using PHPExcel version 1.8.0. I have the same problem and i have found a solution.

For showing the Legends you have to set the `plotGrouping` option to `null`

```
$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_PIECHART,       // plotType
    null,                                           // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($values)-1),                     // plotOrder
    $labels,                                        // plotLabel
    $categories,                                    // plotCategory
    $values                                         // plotValues
);
```

And for showing the PieChart Labels you have to enable data labels by using layout.

```
$layout = new PHPExcel_Chart_Layout();
$layout->setShowVal(TRUE);      
$plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(null, array($series));
```